# What is a better way of saying "building a building"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, metaphors, simile

My sentence is "Creating Software is akin to building a building". This sounds weird and I am looking for a better way to phrase this analogy.

Comment: You want to express difficulty, complexity or a tiring experience?

Comment: Why don't you say it is 'like building a house'?

Comment: Erecting a building? (especially good for tall buildings)

Comment: This is funny, because I constantly have to explain to people that delivering software is *not at all* like building a house...

Comment: Hi Marv. I would love to hear your views :).

Comment: This is not a discussion forum, but essentially all the problems in architecture and building delivery have been solved, patterned and used thousands of times- furthermore buildings have essentially one function (to house or enclose things). Whereas you have to solve a unique problem every time you create a new system. These are broad brush strokes and I know there are wrinkles, shades and exceptions. But this captures the thrust of my arguments against people who can't understand why schedules and costs are not utterly predictable in software delivery.

Comment: Look up synonyms for "building", in both senses.

Comment: Sorry, but proofreading is off-limits here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [***constructing***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/construct) a building?

> **construct**
>   verb
>
> Build or make (something, typically a building, road, or machine):
>   *a company that constructs oil rigs*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/construct

Comment: Ah yes. So stupid of me to miss that!

Comment: @Tariq Ibrahim I *so* do know the feeling of bashing your head against the wall as you grasp for that elusive, fitting word. Glad to help!

Comment: You have perfectly articulated my thoughts now